# How to set a hotkey to write some code

Tags: vim

I want to write the following code when I press mapleader+r. Having read a bunch of tutorials I'm still a wee bit confused how I'd achieve this.

```
file_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');
error_log(print_r(, true));
```

I've already mapped my mapleader to space bar.

Comment: Use a snippet plugin...

Answer (score 2):

Two options:

- Either you define an abbreviation (`:h iab`) or an insert mode mapping (`:h imap`)
- or you install one of the [snippet plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Snippet_Plugin_Comparison) (which are abbreviations on steroids)

I recommend the later approach.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume that you've set your leader key, then all you need is to put the following line into your `.vimrc` file so that you can insert it in **Insert** mode by `<leader>r`.

```
inoremap <leader>r file_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');<cr>error_log(print_r(, true));<cr>
```

**or**
 if you want to insert the code you want in **Normal** mode, you just need to change above line as following:

```
nnoremap <leader>r ifile_put_contents(ini_get('error_log'), '');<cr>error_log(print_r(, true));<esc>
```

Then you can insert the code by `<leader>r`.

Comment: The OP has mapped `<Leader>` to a space.  The map wouldn't make sense in insert mode, he won't be able to write " r"...

Answer (score 1):

you can just map:

```
nnoremap <leader>r ifile_put_......;<cr>error_log....;<esc>
```

Or create a defined macro.

I don't suggest `imap` (insert mapping). Imagine that, you have space as leader, when you type `<space>r` in INSERT mode, those codes will fill... how annoying is it!  E.g. you type `I really like read the book.` It will insert twice!

However for those code snippets, you may want to create a snippet. There are many plugins, which supports code snippets.